# I want to store the ArrayList into offline storage everytime i click on the accept button and retrieve it when the app is reopened

Tags: android

I want to store the Arraythat is in the ArrayList and save it even if the app is closed and reopened again. And i want to retrieve the values whenever the app is opened and display the results

```
    This is my MainActivity

package com.example.vineeth.customlistviewmytrail;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        int test;
        EditText et_period1,et_period2,et_period3,et_period4,et_period5,et_period6,et_period7,et_period8;
        EditText et_number;
        TextView tv_head;

        Button bt_submit,bt_submit2;


        //






        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            et_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_number);
            bt_submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);
            bt_submit2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_submit2);
            tv_head = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_head);



            et_period1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period1);
            et_period2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period2);
            et_period3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period3);
            et_period4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period4);
            et_period5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period5);
            et_period6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period6);
            et_period7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period7);
            et_period8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_period8);


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("text",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.commit();
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("text",MODE_PRIVATE);

            int bouncer = pref.getInt("bounce",0);
            if(bouncer==0)
            {
                tv_head.setText("Enter for Monday");

            }
            else if(bouncer==1)
            {
                tv_head.setText("Enter for Tuesday");

            }
            else  if(bouncer==2)
            {
                tv_head.setText("Enter for Wednesday");

            }
            else if(bouncer ==3)
            {
                tv_head.setText("Enter for Thursday");
            }
            else if(bouncer==4)
            {
                tv_head.setText("Enter for Friday");
            }
            else if(bouncer==5)
            {
                tv_head.setText("Enter for Saturday");
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you for Entering all your values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            bt_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String value = et_number.getText().toString();
                    test = 1;


                    if(value.isEmpty())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {

                        int number = Integer.parseInt(value);


                        if (number < 2) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter valid value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        if (number == 2) {
                            et_period1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (number == 3) {
                            et_period1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (number == 4) {
                            et_period1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (number == 5) {
                            et_period1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (number == 6) {
                            et_period1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            et_period8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (number == 7) {
                            et_period1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (number == 8) {
                            et_period1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            et_period8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });


            bt_submit2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(test==1)
                    {
                        String period1,period2,period3,period4,period5,period6,period7,period8;

                        period1 = et_period1.getText().toString();
                        period2 = et_period2.getText().toString();
                        period3 = et_period3.getText().toString();
                        period4 = et_period4.getText().toString();
                        period5 = et_period5.getText().toString();
                        period6 = et_period6.getText().toString();
                        period7 = et_period7.getText().toString();
                        period8 = et_period8.getText().toString();


                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                        i.putExtra("period1",period1);
                        i.putExtra("period2",period2);
                        i.putExtra("period3",period3);
                        i.putExtra("period4",period4);
                        i.putExtra("period5",period5);
                        i.putExtra("period6",period6);
                        i.putExtra("period7",period7);
                        i.putExtra("period8",period8);

                        startActivity(i);

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter values first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }







                }
            });









        }
    }
```

My SecondActivity

```
This is my secondactivity

package com.example.vineeth.customlistviewmytrail;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv_list;
    Button bt_confirm,bt_clear;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
int bouncer;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    lv_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
    bt_confirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_confirm);
    bt_clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_clear);



    final Intent i = getIntent();
    final String value1 = i.getStringExtra("period1");
    list.add(value1);
    String value2 = i.getStringExtra("period2");
    list.add(value2);
    String value3 = i.getStringExtra("period3");
    list.add(value3);
    String value4,value5,value6,value7,value8;
    value4=i.getStringExtra("period4");
    list.add(value4);
    value5=i.getStringExtra("period5");
    list.add(value5);
    value6=i.getStringExtra("period6");
    list.add(value6);
    value7=i.getStringExtra("period7");
    list.add(value7);
    value8=i.getStringExtra("period8");
    list.add(value8);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

    /*JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("arrays",new JSONArray(list));
    String arrayList = json.toString();*/



    lv_list.setAdapter(adapter);


    bt_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("text",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("text",MODE_PRIVATE);





            bouncer = pref.getInt("bounce",0);


            bouncer = bouncer + 1;


            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);


            editor.putInt("bounce",bouncer);
            editor.commit();

           // Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, bouncer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    bt_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("text",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            bouncer=0;
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });









}
```

}

Comment: You can store arraylist data into sharedprefrence
Just Changing arraylist data to json using gson & store into shared prefrence

Comment: Simply use database or sharedprefrence

Comment: also you can store arraylist in file

Comment: what is the problem in saving?

Comment: Do you any links sir ? I am still a beginner and don't know how to implement json into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a rather easy solution to my question .

I used 2 functions to convert the Array to String format separating by a comma and the other function to convert string back to array by using split.

I stored the string easily in SharedPreferences in a string format and retrieved them back when i wanted and converted them back.

converting array to string code

```
public String convertArrayToString(String[] array)
    {
        String str = "";
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            str = str+array[i];

            if(i<array.length-1)
            {
                str = str+strSeperator;
            }
        }
        return  str;
    }
```

converting String to array code

```
 public static String[] convertStringToArray(String str)
    {
        String[] arr = str.split(strSeperator);
        return arr;
    }
```

and then simply
converted the ArrayList to normal array
like this

```
String[] toArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

and then

I used the convertArrayTostring function and directly stored in a sharedpref file

```
 editor.putString("MondayList",convertArrayToString(toArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in database or shared preferences.

1. Define your model which you can use to store some data in SharedPreferences
2. Add Gson to libraries
3. Get SharedPreferences

   More information about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

   ```
   final String key = "example"; // constant key to retrieve data, must be unique
   final String prefName = "example2" // constant name for preference file
   final SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

   final Gson gson = new Gson();

   // put data
   pref.edit().putString(key, gson.toJson(model)).apply();

   // get data
   final String serialized = pref.getString(key, null); // if there is no data in preferences yet, it returns null
   if (serialized == null){
       // handle no saved data state
   } else {
      final Model model = gson.fromJson(serialized, Model.class);
   }
   ```

That's all. You can make separate methods for every operations, wrap into interface and implement somewhere or make simple `PreferenceStorage / Helper class` for easy access and keep clean architecture.

Comment: Thank you !  I will definitely try !

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the following code: 

For Saving:**

```
String mySavedList= new Gson().toJson(list);
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("My_SAVED_LIST", mySavedList).commit();
```

**For Retrieving:**

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new Gson().fromJson(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("My_SAVED_LIST", ""), new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                }.getType());
```